# How to force a reboot in post-install in Inno Setup

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

In my setup I have to install an external driver.
In some rare cases the installation fails and I have to remove the old driver and reboot before I can try again.

I install the external driver in the `ssPostInstall`.

```pascal
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    if Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\external.exe'), '-install', '', SW_SHOW,
            ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
    begin
      { handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code }
    end
    else begin
      { handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code }
      bReboot := true;
    end;
  end;

function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := bReboot;
end;
```

Unfortunately this does not work since `NeedRestart` is called before `ssPostInstall`.

Is there any other way to trigger a reboot?
I don't want to set `AlwaysRestart = yes`

I could let pop up a `MsgBox` to inform the user and tell them what to do. But it would be much nicer if it could be handled within of the setup automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the installation sooner. For example immediately after the `external.exe` is installed using [`AfterInstall`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptinstall):

```
[Files]
Source: "external.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; AfterInstall: InstallDriver
```

```pascal
[Code]
procedure InstallDriver;
begin
  if Exec(ExpandConstant('{app}\external.exe'), '-install', '', SW_SHOW,
          ewWaitUntilTerminated, ResultCode) then
  begin
    { handle success if necessary; ResultCode contains the exit code }
  end
    else
  begin
    { handle failure if necessary; ResultCode contains the error code }
    bReboot := true;
  end;
end;
```

---

Another option is to use `ssInstall` step (or even [`PrepareToInstall` event](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=PrepareToInstall)) and extract the file programmatically using [`ExtractTemporaryFile`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_extracttemporaryfile).

---

Btw, if `external.exe` is only an installer, you may want to "install" it to `{tmp}` (to get it automatically deleted).

Comment: Thanks - this works. I will need the exe still later, so I must not delete it.